# How to get an array value after explode?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have passed a value from one page to another in array. I can extract first two vars by explode but I can't get the third value which is formed in an array out.

This is my array:

```
$user_rate=$_POST['user_rate'];//15000|ss|Array
list($total,$promo,$rate)=explode("|",$user_rate);
```

So I get:

```
$total=15000;
$promo=ss;
$rate=Array;
```

While Array comes from the previous page by looping the daily rate and put in an array. And I need to know what each rate is, so I wrote:

```
foreach($rate as $val){
echo "$val<br>";
}
```

But it shows nothing. How can I get this?

Updated : This is the code before the var is sent.

```
echo "
<tr>
<td align=\"right\" colspan=\"3\">Total</td>
<td align=\"right\"><label for=\"promo_3\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"user_rate\" id=\"promo_3\" value=\"$ss_total|ss|$cost_ss\" />&nbsp;<u><b>".number_format($ss_total)."</b></u></label></td>
<td align=\"right\"><label for=\"promo_1\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"user_rate\" id=\"promo_1\" value=\"$net_total|nc|$cost_nr\" checked/>&nbsp;<u><b>".number_format($net_total)."</b></u></label></td>
</tr>";
```

**AND THIS FORMAT OF VALUE CANNOT CHANGE BECAUSE I NEED IT FOR A LATER JAVASCRIPT EXTRACT**

While **$cost_ss** and **$cost_nr** are derived from database query looping.

```
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$cost_ss[]=$rec['rate_ss'];
$cost_nr[]=$rec['rate_nr'];
}
```

Comment: how do you think the string expands to a PHP array? use serialization/json

Comment: do var_dump($rate); and see what is actually in that variable. My guess it's a string.

Comment: you output $cost_ss like a string although it is an array... if you do echo $array; you will get the string "Array". and thats what happens here. please use serialize($cost_ss) and later do unserialize($data[2]) of your exploded data.

Comment: This is how I've tested, but no luck.

    `$promo=explode("|",$_POST['user_rate']);
foreach(unserialize($promo[2]) as $key=>$val){
 echo "$key=$val<br />";
}`

Answer (score 2):

this probably be a wrong `$user_rate=$_POST['user_rate'];//15000|ss|Array`

you can use `serialize / unserialize` for array

Answer (score 1):

You could `serialize` your array parameters before you pass it. Then `unserialize` them on the 2nd page.

```
$rate = serialize($rate);
```

On your 2nd page before you run it through the loop:

```
$rate = unserialize($rate);
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, many answers and no luck... i'll try it again:

you have an array $rate before you submit your form:

```
foreach($rate as $val){
   echo "$val<br>";
}
```

and you want to add $ss_total and the string "ss" and submit it
so you need to:

```
$newarray = array('rate'=>$rate, 'type'=>'ss', 'ss_total'=>$ss_total); 
// now you have a 2-dimensional array ($newarray)

// the next step is to prepare it for form-submitting (serialize and base64_encode):
$stringvalue = base64_encode(serialize($newarray));    

// ok, now you are able to submit it as radio-field-value:
echo '<input type="radio" name="user_rate" id="promo_3" value="'.$stringvalue.'" />';
```

when the form is submitted you get a serialized and encoded string in $_POST['user_rate'], you can do an echo if you'd like to see how it looks.

Now you need to base64_decode and unserialize:

```
$arr = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['user_rate']));
```

and you have now full access to your array:

```
echo $arr['type']."<br />";

echo $arr['ss_total']."<br />";
echo $arr['rate']['index_of_rate']; // i dont know the keys of rate array...
```

access $arr in javascript:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "var jsarr = ".json_encode($arr).";\n";
echo "alert(jsarr.ss_total);\n";
echo "</script>";
```

I hope you get it now.

Comment: ok i got it... it works but your user_rate itself seems to be incorrect. The string Array is not what you want. So you need to fix it one step earlier, before your submit of post-data.

Comment: Steven, I've tried to extract the array before it send by using "foreach" and it works. Any idea?

Comment: yes but we need the code which converts this array to the following string: 15000|ss|Array. I think you should use the serialize stuff instead.

Comment: I've updated my code of sending the variables. Please re-check.

Comment: Thanks for the tried but the format of "value" cannot be changed because I need it for a later javascript.

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio][name=promo_code]").click(function(){
        var arr = this.value.split('|');
        $("#total").val(arr[0]);
        $("#promo_type").val(arr[1]);
    }); 
});`

Comment: if you need it in JS you can json_encode($arr) instead of split('|')! You will get an object and you can access all fields of the array from js

Comment: There is another input box below the radio selection. It is a total cost which is splited from the first array of "user_rate" input. Here is the code `function add(caller){ total.value = total.value*1 + caller.value*1}
function subtract(caller){ total.value = total.value*1 - caller.value*1}`

Answer (score 1):

you can encode the values on the page as

```
implode("|", array($total, $promo, implode(",",$rate));
```

Then decode it with

```
list($total, $promo, $rates) = explode("|", $_POST["user_rate"]);
$rates = explode(",", $rates);
```

Comment: I can't change the format of value for the input it needs to be in : `<input type="hidden" name="user_rate" value="$ss_total|ss|$cost_ss" />` because I need it for a later javascript extract string.

Answer (score 1):

Using serialize is definitely the key to getting this to work, but base64_encode() is the **ideal** way to make it less obfuscated.  When you only use serialize, then you get semicolons, commas, double quotes, single quotes, and several other characters that could cause problems when you pass them through to your script that reassembles it.

For instance,
after serializing an array, you will get this, like Sidux pointed out

```
a:3:{i:0;s:4:"toto";i:1;s:4:"titi";i:2;a:2:{i:0;s:4:"coco";i:1;s:4:"cici";}}
```

When you add base64_encode to the mix you will get an easier value to work with.

```
YTozOntpOjA7czo0OiJ0b3RvIjtpOjE7czo0OiJ0aXRpIjtpOjI7YToyOntpOjA7czo0OiJjb2NvIjtpOjE7czo0OiJjaWNpIjt9fQ==
```

With this, you can easily send/receive your saved array without any trimming, adding of slashes, etcetera.

Assuming you send your data this way, your new code will look like this

```
$user_rate=$_POST['user_rate'];//15000|ss|Array
list($total,$promo,$rate)=explode("|",$user_rate);
$rate = unserialize( base64_decode($rate) );
```

Now, `$rate` is a functional array

Comment: Zane, I've tried this but still not work. The think I wonder is why I can't see anything out of "$rate"???

Comment: you should receive an error at least when you put $rate into the foreach, because it expects an Array.  If you get nothing at all, it means you either have errors set to not display, or $rate actually is a blank array.

Comment: Zane, Before the array is sent. I tried "foreach" it and it shows every rate correctly.

Comment: This is how I tried : `foreach($cost_ss as $key=>$val){echo "$key=$val,";}` and it shows : `0=2400,1=2400,2=2400,3=2400,4=2400,5=2400,6=2400,7=2400,8=2400,9=2400,10=2400,11=2400,12=2400,13=2400,`

Comment: Can you provide the actual code you are using to send the data to the other script.  Is it AJAX? Are you submitting a form? In other words, how are your POSTing the data?

Comment: Zane, I just updated my script to the original code before it sent. Please check.

Comment: if `$cost_ss` is an array like that, then why are you putting it into your HTML?
`value=\"$ss_total|ss|$cost_ss\"`

Comment: You can't send PHP arrays through POST, only strings.. and integers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30849/discussion-between-zane-e-dockery-and-wilf)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think that i understand you probleme, when you passe and array from as string try to "serialize" it and "unserialize" it in the other page, for exemple :

```
$array = serialize(array('toto', 'titi', array('coco', 'cici')));
```

will give you somthing like this

`a:3:{i:0;s:4:"toto";i:1;s:4:"titi";i:2;a:2:{i:0;s:4:"coco";i:1;s:4:"cici";}}`

and if you use`unserialize($array);` it will give you your array back

Comment: Sidux, you mean that I need to rewrite my way of sending array into:

    <input type="hidden" name="user_rate" value="<?=array(serialize(array('15000','ss',array($rate_array))?>" />

Comment: You can use it like this or you can send it by ajax, there is also json_encode and json_decode

Comment: Sidux, I can't change the format of value for this input. Because I still need it for a javascript extract on page as well.

Comment: You still can create an other hidden input, or use ajax

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help. I've re-designed the way of sending values. Now problem solved!