# Why array becomes a text "Array" instead of variables?

Tags: php, arrays, error-handling, echo

According to the prior post [I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817377/php-how-to-get-an-array-value-after-explode/16817445?noredirect=1#comment24245601_16817445). I tried hours to find out the answer. Till now there's no luck. But I getting with something with the array.

I echo the value of `$_POST[user_rate]` and it's = **Array**

So I tried to get the first array of user_rate by doing this:

```
echo $_POST['user_rate'][0];
```

And it only shows **A** instead of a value. I expected 2400 because the previous page I sent the array from **user_rate[]** (you can click the link above to see what happens back there).

Now the question is why it turns **A** instead of value?

Update: this is the value of user_rate after I ran the code it.

```
foreach($user_rate as $key=>$val){echo "$key=$val<br />";}

0=2400
1=2400
2=2400
3=2400
4=2400
5=2400
6=2400
7=2400
8=2400
9=2400
10=2400
11=2400
12=2400
13=2400
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the key is 0 ( numeric zero )

Comment: Please state `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: php_nub_qq, yes it's zero

Comment: @php_nub_qq: It is zero, the reason it shows 'A' is because `$_POST['user_rate']` is a string.

Comment: @DaveChen, It's still shows "A" for print_r().

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['user_rate']);` show?

Comment: It is not possible it displays NULL. [var_dump documentation](http://php.net/var_dump)

Comment: @Jocelyn I updated the code above. Please check it.

Comment: In general, it is best to improve an existing question, rather than to create a simplified duplicate. This is essentially the same problem, as far as I can tell.

Comment: What are you showing us? `$_POST['user_rate']` or `$user_rate`?! For debugging and figuring out what you're actually working with, **always** use `var_dump`, not `echo`.

Comment: @halfer that's another one of OP's questions

Comment: @halfer, I need an answer to this question not the suggestion of being duplicated. And obviously the two posts are not the same. If you read it clearly enough. The one I linked to is about to extract the array of a variable. But this one is about why is becomes text instead of value. Because they're different so I created a new one. I'm sitting here for many hours to see a solution not your kind of answer!

Comment: @Wilf you still haven't provided a `var_dump` of your `$_POST`. You haven't really provided us with that much of value.

Comment: @brbcoding, I've tried but it turned NULL. any idea?

Comment: Why are you showing us the content of `$user_rate` if your issue is with `$_POST['user_rate']`?! They are 2 entirely different variables.

Comment: The value of `$_POST['user_rate']` cannot both be `Array` and `null`. Take a step back, take a deep breath, and post all information available as clearly as possible. Post code, what you expect it to do, what you actually get, **and a `var_dump` of all relevant variables** in this code. We cannot answer a question by getting piecemeal information from the comment section; we need one coherent block of information.

Answer (score 0):

The var you are echoing is a string containing 'Array'

When accessing a string as of it was an array, it will behave likean array of characters.

In this case it contains A - R -R - A - Y

Hence the first item [0] contains "A"

Since you expect a numeric in the post var I suggest you check the php script that does the Post request. Your error lays there

Comment: Well, I tried to extract the array of $user_rate and it just fine. But after it sent across the page. The variables are gone just only "Array" left.

Comment: Show us the code you use for sending. And remember,you cant echo an entire Array to Html. If you try to echo an array object, it will be converted to the string Array

Comment: Actually to be more precise $_POST is an array but its items themselves can never be arrays because of how post requests work and how PHP manages post vars

Comment: It's something like this : `echo "
<tr>
<td align=\"right\" colspan=\"3\">Total</td>
<td align=\"right\"><label for=\"promo_3\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"user_rate\" id=\"promo_3\" value=\"$ss_total|ss|$cost_ss\" />&nbsp;<u><b>".number_format($ss_total)."</b></u></label></td>
<td align=\"right\"><label for=\"promo_1\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"user_rate\" id=\"promo_1\" value=\"$net_total|nc|$cost_nr\" checked/>&nbsp;<u><b>".number_format($net_total)."</b></u></label></td>
</tr>";`. You can see the full version from the link above.

Comment: Your problem lays here : `value=\"$net_total|nc|$cost_nr\"`. This will produce something like `value="Array|nc|62547"` in your Html. Just do View Source in your browser before submitting

Comment: Why it begins with Array. From the variable in value. I would like it to be formatted as : value="15000|ss|Array"

Comment: `$net_total|nc|$cost_nr` from left to right. $net_total is the array, correct? So it starts with Array. It is followed by `|nc|`. So together you now have `Array|nc|`. Then it is followed by $cost_nr ... I don't know if that is an array, a string or  an integer. But whatever it is, it will be put behind `Array|nc|`

Comment: @Wilf is the question answered?